# Parsing AJAX JSON Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm calling this AJAX call,

```
 function y() {
    $.get( "url", function(result) {
       if(result.status == "success") {
           window.location.href = 'https://dummyurl.com';
        } 
    });
 }
```

here is my response from the AJAX call:

```
)]}',
{"status":"success","message":"cookies and session are successfully invalidated","url":"http://localhost.xxx.com"}
```

In my success promise, I'm trying to check if the status value is `success`, I'm redirecting it to some URL. But the problem is it never goes to the if statement.

However if i remove `)]}',` from JSON response it is working fine. I need a solution with `)]}',` in the JSON response, because I cannot remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the default jQuery converter to automatically handle your JSON:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        "text json": function(result) {
            //If my json starts with ")]}'," then remove it and return valid json
            if (result.substr(0, 5) === ")]}',") {
                return JSON.parse(result.substr(5));
            }
            //Else just parse the json
            return JSON.parse(result);
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can make your request normally:

```
function y() {
    $.get( "url", function(result) {
       if(result.status == "success") {
           window.location.href = 'https://dummyurl.com';
        } 
    });
 }
```

**Demo:**

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        "text json": function(result) {
         //If my json starts with ")]}'," then remove it and return valid json
            if (result.substr(0, 5) === ")]}',") {
                return JSON.parse(result.substr(5));
            }
            //Else just parse the json
            return JSON.parse(result);
        }
    }
});


$.get("https://gistcdn.githack.com/iRbouh/e603d1c394dc2873bc2f3637902d0c9a/raw/f19e973447843ef42ef823e5ebb595e2574e7392/secure-JSON.json", function(result) {
    if(result.status === "success") {
      alert('Valid JSON !');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```